# Windows another RAID 5 fails

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2

i have googled the web but could not come up with any answers.
I have a windows softwareraid "5" (yes plz hate me for this) with 3x3TB disks, one disk recensently failed. I have just replaced the bad disk with a new one.
But i have still no way to add the new disk to the "old" raid, and the bad drive is still listing as missing.

I have tried converting the new disk to mbr, gpt, dynamic and basic. No luck there to get more options..

My raid contanes loooooots of movies and tvshow and so on, so it not that important. But i would like to know if all is completly lost or recovery able?

Here is a img of the disk management. Disk 0 and 1 is the old working disk in the raid, yes dey hare SMART cheked. Disk 2 is the new replacement.
Disk 4 is my other raid witch ofc is real hardware raided...

[image: Windows Disk management]

I will be super happy for any response :-)

Comment: Did you try "reactivating" already?

Comment: Yes, but i get the error message: The attempted operation connot be completed. The selected volume is offline.

Comment: RAID5 should not be used for arrays with a) sata disks, or b) disks larger than 1TB each.

Answer (score 1):

Take a decent look at the state of your array. It is not "Failed redundancy" as would be the case with a single-disk failure. It is ***"Failed"*** meaning that you are likely seeing a 2-disk failure.

In general, rebuilding a RAID-5 array [is straightforward](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc938528.aspx) once you've plugged a new empty disk and initialized it as "Dynamic":

> To replace a stripe in the RAID-5 volume, you need a dynamic disk with unallocated space that is at least as large as the stripe to repair. If you don't have a dynamic disk with enough unallocated space, the Repair Volume command is unavailable.

Check the event log to see if your system has kicked one of the remaining apparently functional drives out of the array before. Now if you are confident that the two remaining disks should contain all (or at least most) of your data, you might try your luck with data recovery tools (at least some do claim capability to [find and re-assemble lost arrays](https://www.runtime.org/raid-recovery-windows.htm)). Alternatively, if you have spare disks you can copy the raw data to and are willing to experiment, you might check out if your array would assemble using a Linux Live CD and either `mdadm` or `dm-raid`.

Comment: I did a "smart" check earlier, and the two disks are healthy. I was depending on the strangforward guid. but i dont get the option to recover (greyed out). Could it help to delete the "missing drive", and then see if i could rebuild with the new disk? Thank you for a great answer :)

Comment: @starR you can't *"Repair"* because the state of the array is *"Failed"*. Even if SMART says that the disks are healthy, one of them might have been kicked out of the array at some point due to a transient failure. Or SMART is simply lying (possible, although rather improbable). At any rate, your array has lost two disks out of three which is considered a total loss as far as the RAID5 reassembly algorithm is concerned.

Comment: I was afraid so, guess i just gonna delete the raid and start fresh. Thank you, have a nice weekend :)